# Angular - throw $injectorMinErr('nomod', "Module '{0}' is not available! You either misspelled

Tags: angularjs, express

I generated a basic express 4.0 and updated index.ejs to following. Once I added reference to Angular, I started to see exception thrown on Chrome. I saw couple posts that talked about this exception but the answer still could not resolve my issue. Could this be an with Express instead of Angular? 
          throw $injectorMinErr('nomod', "Module '{0}' is not available! You either misspelled " +
             "the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you " +
             "specify the dependencies as the second argument.", name);

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
<title><%= title %></title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
</script>
</head>
 <body >
  <h1><%= title %></h1>
  <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  <form method='post' action='test'>
    <input type='text' name='text'>
    <input type='submit'>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

So use `ngApp="myApp"`

Comment: I thought ng-app and ngapp are the same. Aside, i still get the same error after trying your suggestion.

Comment: I've added also JQuery as a dependency
http://jsfiddle.net/verodigiorgio/x0xfaqzh/1/